# Help in figuring out a replacement rear wheel for Huffy Savannah 27"

Tags: wheels, replacement

I have a Huffy Savannah 27" bike that I bought about 6 years ago and need to find a replacement rear wheel.  The bearings went bad, but the rest of the bike is almost brand new.  The tire is a 700c x 38.  How can I find suitable replacement?  I don't care about brand, only that it will work with the tire.

Comment: Why not just get the bearings fixed?

Answer (score 3):

New ball bearings will cost less than a new wheel - the order of $5 for a bag.   It may be that your bearings are okay just mal-adjusted so there may be no cost for parts.

You'll need a cone spanner and a conventional spanner, some grease, and cleaning gear (rags/ solvent like petrol or whatever)

Since its the rear wheel, you'll need the special tool to remove your cassette/freewheel as well.  Even buying one of these its still cheaper than replacing the wheel.

This is a good start:

Another option is to find a bike coop in your city and ask for some assistance.  Wheel bearings are straightforward fixes.

If you don't feel that you can do this, a bike shop can change your bearings for half the cost of a new wheel.

Comment: @andy256 fair call, done. Feel free to edit any answer  - nobody owns an answer, I would not take offense at any improvements.